# "Дефолтовые решения"

Tags: стилистика, семантика, смысл, заимствования

"Отсюда возникло и неприятие к тем дефолтовым решениям, которые навязаны традициями".

**1.** Что здесь означает словосочетание **дефолтовые решения**? **2.** Допустимо ли написание **неприятие к решениям**?

Comment: "Неприятие к решениям" надо заменять на "неприятие решений" или "_отношение_ неприятия к решениям" (как вид отношения к решениям) - существительное здесь сохраняет свойства родственного переходного глагола (не приемлю) и требует прямого дополнения. Видимо, возникла путаница со словом "неприязнь" (к кому).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это цитата из статьи о лайфхакерском движении. Статья, возможно, переведена с английского, поэтому вероятны ошибки. Дефолтовые решения - правильно писать "дефолтные"  - здесь означает "стандартные". Неприятие (чего?) решений.

Comment: Правильно писать "стандартные", "обычные". Единственное литературное значение "дефолт" в русском языке сугубо экономическое.

Comment: С точки зрения орфографии, правильно писать "дефолтные", а не "дефолтовые". С точки зрения стилистики лучше писать "стандартные". По поводу слова "дефолтный": оно употребляется также как понятие, связанное с компьютерами, в значении “установленный производителем" и "значение по умолчанию". Поскольку лайфхакерское движении зародилось среди программистов, употребление здесь слова "дефолтный" как компьютерного сленга мне кажется допустимым.